# Why does this C++ code give different output on different compilers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, gcc, c++11, compiler-construction

I realize that there are many questions with this title on SO, but all of the ones I've found did things like `i = ++i` or `f(f(f(x)))`, neither of which are in this code. It's an attempt at a backtracking solution to [this](http://codeforces.com/contest/339/problem/C). I have some experience with C but I've just started trying to pick up C++, and I've been doing Codeforces problems for practice. The snippet below is the main body of the program. `main`, which I have not shown, deals with input and output. I used global variables here for `weights`, `answer`, and `max_depth` in the interest of keeping each stack frame of `solve` as small as possible.

The input that's causing trouble is `weights = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}` and `max_depth = 1000`.  When I compile this with `g++ std=C++11 file.cpp`, it gives "4 3 2 3 4 3 2 3 4 ... 3 2 1," which is the correct answer. When Codeforces compiles it, it gives "9 10 9 10 9 10 9 10...", which is incorrect. My guess is that the order that `for(int i : weights)` traverses the vector in is not defined by the standard, but even then, I don't see why it would make any difference. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string answer = "";
vector<int> weights; 
int max_depth;

bool solve(int left_scale, int right_scale, int last_added, int depth){
  bool is_left = (depth % 2) == 0;

  int new_weight;
  int weight_to_inc = is_left ? left_scale : right_scale;
  int weight_to_exceed = is_left ? right_scale : left_scale;

  if (depth == max_depth){
    return true;
  }


  for(int i : weights){
    if (i != last_added){
      new_weight = weight_to_inc + i;
      if (new_weight > weight_to_exceed){
        bool ans =  solve(is_left ? new_weight : left_scale,
                          is_left ? right_scale : new_weight,
                          i, depth + 1);
        if (ans){
          stringstream ss;
          ss << i;
          answer.append(ss.str() + " ");
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

void start_solve(void){
  if (solve(0, 0, 0, 0)){
    return;
  }

  answer = "";
}
```

(The full code that I submitted, if it makes any difference, is [here](http://codeforces.com/contest/339/submission/4368729).)

EDIT:

In case anyone stumbles on this looking for an answer to the Codeforces problem: the issue with this code is that "answer" is reversed. Changing `answer.append(ss.str() + " ")` to `answer = ss.str() + answer` is the shortest fix that gets it working.

Comment: Without looking at the code, the answer probably lies in you doing something that leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Where is the main function?

Comment: And by the way, the order of which the range-based `for` statement iterates is very well defined, as it uses normal iterators behind the scene. See e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for how it works.

Comment: @user1131467 It's in the link at the bottom because I wanted to avoid copy+pasting the whole program into here, although I can if people would find it clearer?

Comment: And @JoachimPileborg yes, I'm aware of that. That's why I'm asking the question. Where is it? (I had this tagged as undefined-behavior but switched it out for algorithms because I thought it was more likely that undefined behavior was exposing an error in my logic rather than causing a problem in and of itself.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does this C++ code give different output on different compilers?

It doesn't give different output.

> When I compile this with g++ std=C++11 file.cpp, it gives "4 3 2 3 4 3 2 3 4 ... 3 2 1," which is the correct answer. When Codeforces compiles it, it gives "9 10 9 10 9 10 9 10...", which is incorrect.

I believe you are misinterpreting [your test results on the codeforces server](http://codeforces.com/contest/339/submission/4368729).

The correct answer is "9 10 9 10...".

The output of your program is "4 3 2 3 4 3..." on both the codeforces server and your local workstation.

So your algorithm is wrong, and the output of the program is consistent.

You are mixing up the two fields on the test results "Output" and "Answer".

Check your test results again.